# Different output path for each user

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I did a `Get latest version` from our Team Foundation Server, and I saw that the output paths for the projects are on a drive which I don't have on my laptop. Changing this path to something else would work on my laptop but it is not the perfect way because when I check-in this change, then all the other developers will get `my` path.

I'm sure there must an easy solution for this.

Comment: shouldn't the output path be set as relative? like `..\..\bin\Release`? how come it was set to another drive that is not accessible to every developer?

Comment: Don't ask me why :-), but how can the path be set relatively then?

Comment: Set it in project properties->Build->Output path, don't use an absolution path like `C:\Output`, use a relative path; for C# project, usually it is set as "bin\Debug" and "bin\Release", check in your changes, and inform your coworkers about this breaking change...